# Joining 2 dataframes and collecting only the unique values in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes, the first one that is called questions_version1 and the second one called questions_version2.

```
questions_version1
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+
|  question |answer    |version    | total_answers
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+
|eye color  | blue     |  1        |  15000       |
|eye color  | brown    |  1        |  32000       |
|eye color  | green    |  1        |  5000        |
|hair color | brown    |  1        |  47000       |
|hair color | blonde   |  1        |  3000        |
|hair color | white    |  1        |  2000        |
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

```
questions_version2
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+
|  question |answer    |version    | total_answers
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+
|eye color  | blue     |  1        |  15000       |
|eye color  | green    |  1        |  5000        |
|eye color  | hazel    |  2        |  9000        |
|hair color | brown    |  1        |  47000       |
|hair color | white    |  1        |  2000        |
|hair color | red      |  2        |  500         |
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

How do I join both so I can get all the values in questions_version2 that doesn't exist in questions_version1 without duplicating all the repeated values that exist in both?

The final result would be something like this:

```
questions_1_and_2_merged
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+
|  question |answer    |version    | total_answers
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+
|eye color  | blue     |  1        |  15000       |
|eye color  | brown    |  1        |  32000       |
|eye color  | green    |  1        |  5000        |
|eye color  | hazel    |  2        |  9000        |
|hair color | brown    |  1        |  47000       |
|hair color | blonde   |  1        |  3000        |
|hair color | white    |  1        |  2000        |
|hair color | red      |  2        |  500         |
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

Could you all help me with this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could loop through the second list and do:

> if elem in questions_version1:
> continue
> else:
> questions_version1.append(elem)

Comment: That's actually a dataframe, not a list. Unfortunately that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents:

You can do union and then drop duplicates, that should suffice.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

# create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Create DataFrame").getOrCreate()

# define schema for the DataFrame
schema = StructType([
    StructField("question", StringType(), True),
    StructField("answer", StringType(), True),
    StructField("version", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("total_answers", IntegerType(), True)
])

# create questions_version1 DataFrame
data1 = [("eye color", "blue", 1, 15000),
        ("eye color", "brown", 1, 32000),
        ("eye color", "green", 1, 5000),
        ("hair color", "brown", 1, 47000),
        ("hair color", "blonde", 1, 3000),
        ("hair color", "white", 1, 2000)]

questions_version1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=schema)

# create questions_version2 DataFrame
data2 = [("eye color", "blue", 1, 15000),
        ("eye color", "green", 1, 5000),
        ("eye color", "hazel", 2, 9000),
        ("hair color", "brown", 1, 47000),
        ("hair color", "white", 1, 2000),
        ("hair color", "red", 2, 500)]

questions_version2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=schema)


questions_union = questions_version1.union(questions_version2).dropDuplicates().orderBy('question')

questions_union.show()
```

Please check below for sample output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option to get all rows in the second table that are not part of the first table would be an [anti-join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html#anti-join):

> An anti join returns values from the left relation that has no match with the right.

The result can the be [unioned](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union.html) with the first table.

```python
df1 = ...
df2 = ...

df1.union (
    df2.join(df1, df1.columns, how='anti')
).show()
```

Result:

```
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------+
|   question|    answer|version|total_answers|
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------+
|eye color  | blue     |      1|        15000|
|eye color  | brown    |      1|        32000|
|eye color  | green    |      1|         5000|
|hair color | brown    |      1|        47000|
|hair color | blonde   |      1|         3000|
|hair color | white    |      1|         2000|
|eye color  | hazel    |      2|         9000|
|hair color | red      |      2|          500|
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------+
```